# How to calculate a progressive sum within an Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query, let's call it `qry_01`, that produces a set of data similar to this:

```
ID   N    CN   Sum
1    4    0    0
2    3    3    3
5    4    4    7
8    3    3    10
```

The values shown in this query actually come from a chain of queries and from a bunch of different tables.

The corrected value `CN` is calculated within the query, and counts `N` if the `ID` is not 1, and 0 if it is 1.

The `Sum` is the value I want to calculate by progressively summing up the `CN` values.

I tried to use `DSUM`, but I came out with nothing.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery in the following way:

```sql
select t.id, t.n, t.cn, (select sum(u.cn) from qry_01 u where u.id <= t.id) as [sum]
from qry_01 t
```

Comment: Thanks Lee Mac, I tried to get some understanding about subqueries, but maybe it's still far beyond my knowledge.
I don't understand what t and u are, and whether I have to put the subquery in the field Sum: <subquery>, or in the WHERE section of the actual query.

Comment: @ClaudioTomasoni `t` & `u` are merely aliases to allow me to reference the source data `qry_01` more than once (and save me some typing) - they are the same as writing `select [field] as [alias] ...` You shouldn't need to modify the SQL that I have provided - simply create a new query and paste the SQL into the SQL view.

Comment: thanks! It worked.
I just had to modify the WHERE condition, because I needed to order the list on a date. So I added also a date field to the query and changed WHERE u.id <= t.id to WHERE u.date <= t.date.